# best way to play audio reliably and quickly in webpage?

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I would like to play a short audio file (like a notification sound) when people hit the html button. also stay on the same page?

Is there any jQuery, prototype js way to do it hopefully can do it without FLASH.

Comment: there's html5 `<audio>` tag...

Comment: just add an src and an `onclick` for linking

Comment: It is not possible play audio without flash now. SoundManager 2 is a good suggestion from @HeavyWave. +1

Comment: it is SO possible without flash. GUYS. HTML5 EXISTS.

Answer (score 3):

The most popular javascript framework for that sort of thing is [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/), which is used by Last.FM among others. It supports HTML5 as well as Flash for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

there's html5 `<audio>` tag... just add an `src` and an `onclick` for user actions